# Using Struts 2 select without applying list attribute, instead use option --> is it OK?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am migrating struts1 to Struts 2 web project.

Below is Struts 1 code.

```
<html:select property="dobYear" styleId="dobYear" styleClass="text_field text2" style="width:70px" onchange="loadDayOptions(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value, getElement('dobMonth').options[getElement('dobMonth').options.selectedIndex].value, getElement('dobDay'));">
    <html:option value="">--</html:option>
    <% 
        int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int fromYear = thisYear - 17;
        int toYear = 1900;
        for(int i=fromYear; i>=toYear; i--){
        
     %>
    <html:option value="<%=String.valueOf(i) %>"><%=String.valueOf(i) %></html:option>
    <%  } %>
</html:select>
```

If I want below code in Struts 2 using `s:select` but without using list attribute, instead using `<option>`, is it OK? Is my syntax correct?

```
<s:select value="#{editForm.dobYear}" name="editForm.dobYear" id="dobYear" styleClass="text_field text2" style="width:70px" onchange="loadDayOptions(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value, getElement('dobMonth').options[getElement('dobMonth').options.selectedIndex].value, getElement('dobDay'));">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <% 
        int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int fromYear = thisYear - 17;
        int toYear = 1900;
        for(int i=fromYear; i>=toYear; i--){
        
     %>
    <option value="<%=String.valueOf(i) %>"><%=String.valueOf(i) %></option>
    <%  } %>
</s:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct. According to TLD the struts select tag should have an empty body.

You can't use struts select tag in that way. But you can convert it to html select

```
<select value="${editForm.dobYear}" name="editForm.dobYear" id="dobYear" styleClass="text_field text2" style="width:70px" onchange="loadDayOptions(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value, getElement('dobMonth').options[getElement('dobMonth').options.selectedIndex].value, getElement('dobDay'));">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <% 
        int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int fromYear = thisYear - 17;
        int toYear = 1900;
        for(int i=fromYear; i>=toYear; i--){

     %>
    <option value="<%=String.valueOf(i) %>"><%=String.valueOf(i) %></option>
    <%  } %>
</select>
```